# How to connect multiple values and display it

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax

I'm making a order-history for a shop.

[image: Database Image]

As you can see some datetime's are the same, that means these are the orders what has to go in the same table.

Example of the Order-History what im trying to make :

**Order 1**

 Beer 1 - (1-9-2016:21:37:20)

 Beer 2 - (1-9-2016:21:37:20)

 Beer 3 - (1-9-2016:21:37:20)

**Order 2**

 Beer 1 - (1-9-2016:21:43:16)

 Beer 2 - (1-9-2016:21:43:16)

 Beer 3 - (1-9-2016:21:43:16)

What i currently have is this :

[image]

As you can see the orders are all in one table and not grouped by their datetime.

Method how i receive my orders:

```
        $scope.callBatch = function () {
        var batchurl = "http://localhost/bierAngular/bierapi.php?action=getBatch";
        $http.get(batchurl).success(function (response) {
            $scope.batch = response;
        });
    };
    $scope.callBatch();
```

How i filled the HTML :

```
  <div class="showlijst">
        <h1>Bestelgeschiedenis</h1>
        <table border="1">
            <tr>
                <td>Naam</td>
                <td>Aantal</td>
                <td>Datum</td>
            </tr>
            <tr ng-repeat="b in batch | filter: datetime">
                <td>{{b.naam}}</td>
                <td>{{b.aantal}}</td>
                <td id="dtime">{{b.datetime}}</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
```

Sorry for my bad english, im trying my best to improve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the response is an array of objects, sort it by date before assigning it to the scope property.
Note: the dates in your example don't have a standard format, you have to replace the separator between date and time, ":", by a "T", change the order into year-month-date, and fill with left-hand zeroes values of 1 digit (done in the example below).

Note 2: To sort in descending order change to: return Date.parse(dates[1])-Date.parse(dates[0]);

```
$scope.callBatch = function () {
  var batchurl = "http://localhost/bierAngular/bierapi.php?action=getBatch";
  $http.get(batchurl).success(function (response) {
    response.sort(function (a, b) {
      var dates = [a.datetime, b.datetime];
      for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        var sep = dates[i].indexOf(":");
        var date = dates[i].substring(0, sep).split("-");
        var time = dates[i].substring(sep+1).split(":");
        for (var j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
          while(date[j].length < 2) {date[j] = "0"+date[j];}
          while(time[j].length < 2) {time[j] = "0"+time[j];}
        }
        dates[i] = date[2]+"-"+date[1]+"-"+date[0]+"T"+time[0]+":"+time[1]+":"+time[2];
      }
      return Date.parse(dates[0])-Date.parse(dates[1]);
    });
    $scope.batch = response;
  });
};
$scope.callBatch();
```

Comment: Hi Dylan, can you upvote the answer clicking on the arrow up above the votes number? If it's valid for you it should be upvoted (I'm new here and trying to gain reputation) Cheers